# How to add ObjectId argument to a mongodb lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am doing a lookup where the local field is an ObjectId and the foreign field is an array of ObjectId's. Performing the lookup gives me the error:

```
arguments to $lookup must be strings
```

I have done similar lookups where the foreign field is not an array (but is an ObjectId) so the error seems to be ambiguous. my database consists two collections: Song and Playlist. A Song can belong to many playlists. I am trying to write an aggregation that returns a matching song that contains an array of playlists the song belongs to:

**Songs:**

```
[
  {
    songName: "In Da Club",
    _id: ObjectId(1)
  },
  {
    songName: "Happy Birthday",
    _id: ObjectId(2)
  },
  {
    songName: "Ode to Joy",
    _id: ObjectId(3)
  }
]
```

**Playlists:**

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId(4)
    playlistName: "PlaylistOne,
    songs: [ObjectId(1), ObjectId(3)]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(5)
    playlistName: "PlaylistTwo,
    songs: [ObjectId(1)]
  }
]
```

**Desired outcome:**

```
{
  songName: "In Da Club",
  _id: ObjectId(1),
  playlists: [
    {
      _id: ObjectId(4),
      playlistName: "PlaylistOne,
    },
    {
      _id: ObjectId(5),
      playlistName: "PlaylistTwo"
    }
  ]
}
```

**The query I tried:**

```
db.songs.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      songName: "In Da Club"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'playlists',
      let: { songId: '$_id'},
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              {
                $in: ["$$songId", "$songs"]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: 'playlists'
    }
  }
])
```

It seems to be a relatively simple query and I'm not sure how I can get around the "arguments passed into lookup must be strings" error since my lookup is based on ObjectId's. Any help would be greatly appreciated! TIA!

Comment: Apart from couple of syntax error in query everything looks fine, Test it here : https://mongoplayground.net/p/85q9qBsL62X , What is your MongoDB version & where is it hosted ?

Comment: ah ok - i was running mongodb version 3.6 locally... i'll upgrade to the latest version and try again. thanks!

Comment: i was on 3.2***

Comment: Give this a try : https://mongoplayground.net/p/C7z4pUdvjN- & let me know ! You might probably get into same issue but let me know what happens..

Comment: ah that works too! i didnt even try that because i assumed it wouldn't work since the foreign field is an array... thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) is introduced in version `3.2` but couple of enhancements are done on it in sub-sequent updates :

**As per docs :**

> Starting MongoDB 3.4, if the localField is an array, you can match the
>   array elements against a scalar foreignField without needing an
>   $unwind stage.
>
> MongoDB 3.6, adds support for executing a pipeline on the joined
>   collection, which allows for specifying multiple join conditions as
>   well as uncorrelated sub-queries.

So the issue might be from mongodb version being low. Anyway for your requirement you can use `$lookup` which is used for single equality join as array is on `foreignField`.

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "playlists",
      localField: "_id", // Scalar value
      foreignField: "songs", // Against an array
      as: "playlists"
    }
  }
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/C7z4pUdvjN-)